# Is it possible to delete a textNode from the DOM within an element?

Tags: javascript, dom, sharepoint

I am using a SharePoint blog and for some odd reason, the post to every blog reads,

**by [object Object] in HR Department**

I am trying to use DOM manipulation to remove this but it's to no avail.  The HTML looks something like the below.  I want to remove **by [object Object] in**

```
<div class="ms-metadata ms-textSmall">
    <span> 
      by [object Object] in <a class="ms-link" id="blgcat" href="https://myPortal.net">IT Department</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
var link = document.getElementById("blgcat").parentNode.textNode;
console.log(link)
var leafSibling = link.previousSibling
link.removeChild(leafSibling)
```

Any idea how to fix? Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/gOrgpKa?editors=0010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Start with just the known element...the link.

Then get the link's previous sibling and remove that from link's parent node.

```js
var link = document.getElementById("blgcat"); 
link.parentNode.removeChild(link.previousSibling)
```

```html
<div class="ms-metadata ms-textSmall">
    <span> 
      by [object Object] in <a class="ms-link" id="blgcat" href="https://myPortal.net">IT Department</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW!! Thank you so much. I need to look at that a few times and wrap my head around that.  LOL... thanks again!  makes sense.

Comment: Or even simpler `link.previousSibling.textContent=''`